# Securing a dedicated server

Tags: dedicated-server

We are building a first person shooter and we want to give out a dedicated server program. The only problem is that we have a leveling system and we don't want people to hack our dedicated servers and level themselves up. The way it is set up now is that the dedicated server connects to our main servers and report kills and such which we record to their profiles. So I guess my question is how do we check to make sure that the dedicated servers have not been altered when they connect to our main servers? Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to try calculating the hash of the dedicated server and making sure that is correct when the server connects. This is probably pretty easy to fool though.